# Apply different classes and styles when in 'live preview' pane

Tags: live-preview

Is there any way of adding a class onto a page body when it is viewed within the 'live preview' pane?

I can then use this to make things either show or not show.

I want to do this to highlight specific things to content editors that I don't feel are worth highlighting to regular users.

I think I can only do this by hanging rules off a special 'preview only' class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Craft's Request service has a built-in method for this, [`isLivePreview`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.request#isLivePreview).

Here's how to only display content in the live preview view:

```
{% if craft.request.isLivePreview %}
    <p>Only appears in live preview.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Spot on. Cheers.